# How to get a specific index from nested array States?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Hello i have a state like this;

```
{
  "id": "8",
  "tablename": "demo_1",
  "segments": "segment_1"
},
{
  "id": "9",
  "tablename": "demo_2",
  "segments": "segment_2"
}
```

I want to take `segments` values from `tablename`. Like this:

```
this.state.MYSTATE.map[tablename:'demo_1'];
```

But ofc this wont work. Any help?

Comment: use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for your array like this `this.state.MYSTATE.findIndex(({tablename})=>tablename=='demo_1')`

Comment: or ..  this.state.MYSTATE.find((x)=> x.tablename =='demo_1')  OR this.state.MYSTATE.find((x)=> x.tablename =='demo_1').tablename

Comment: @NarendraJadhav thanks thats work :) pls write this as an answer so i can mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method for array.

The `findIndex()` method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it returns -1, indicating no element passed the test.

**DEMO**

```js
const data =[{
    "id": "8",
    "tablename": "demo_1",
    "segments": "segment_1"
  },{
    "id": "9",
    "tablename": "demo_2",
    "segments": "segment_2"
  }];
  
let index = data.findIndex(({tablename})=>tablename=='demo_1');

console.log(index);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a `filter` followed by a `map`

```js
const data = [{
  "id": "8",
  "tablename": "demo_1",
  "segments": "segment_1"
},
{
  "id": "9",
  "tablename": "demo_2",
  "segments": "segment_2"
}]

const segments = data
  .filter(item => item.tablename === 'demo_1')
  .map(item => item.segments)
  
console.log(segments)
```

The filter will filter all the entry with tablename equal to demo_1 and map will return the segments values of these filtered results